# ¿Como prevenir perdida de estilo de un boton cuando el contenedor principal pierde el focus?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un `UserControl` que contiene varios elementos, pero hay dos que me estan dando problemas; un `ToggleButton` y un `TreeView`.

Cuando tengo información en el TreeView, al seleccionar un elemento (cabe mencionar que tengo tres `HierarchicalDataTemplate` en el TreeView) y  despues hago un `.Clear()` al modelo, el estilo del `ToggleButton` desaparece.

En el estilo del botón coloque `MultiTrigger` para verificar si estaba seleccionado y si el `UserControl` no tenía el `Focus`. Si esto se cumple mantengo el estilo correcto.

```
<MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="UserControl.IsFocused" Value="False" />
    <Condition Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True" />
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

Esto me funciono en unas situaciones, pero existen otras en las que no.

**"Funciona"** cuando el TreeView tiene elementos en el `SortDescription`, pero si no los tiene, el estilo del botón desaparece y se ve como si estuviera inactivo.

Coloque funciones en los eventos `LostFocus` & `GotFocus` del `UserControl` para detectar las pérdidas y ganancia de focus en la ventana, pero al borrar el modelo del TreeView el `LostFocus` no se ejecuta.

## Edición

**WPF** actual de mi TreeView

```
<TreeView Name="NetworkTreeView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" SelectedItemChanged="NetworkTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeView_ExpandedChange" TreeViewItem.Collapsed="TreeView_ExpandedChange">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:NetTreeProtocol}" ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewMenu}">
                <Image Source="/Resources/Images/NodesGroup.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelCount}" Style="{StaticResource LabelCountStyle}"/>                
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:NetTreeChannel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Pans}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewMenu}">
                <Image Source="/Resources/Images/NodesGroup.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelCount}" Style="{StaticResource LabelCountStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:NetTreePan}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SortNodes}">
                    <Binding Path="Nodes"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="RdSortByArrival"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="RdSortByShort"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="RdSortByLong"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="BtnSortOptions"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewMenu}">
                <Image Source="/Resources/Images/NodesGroup.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - " Style="{StaticResource LongAddressStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelLongAddress}" FontWeight="Bold" Name="itemLongAddress" Style="{StaticResource LongAddressStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelCount}" Style="{StaticResource LabelCountStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:NetTreeNode}">
            <Grid Width="Auto">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Resources/Images/NodesItem.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LabelLongAddress}" Name="itemLongAddress" Style="{DynamicResource LongAddressStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**CS** actual del `UserControl`

```
public Constructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    viewModel = new NETreeViewModel();
    NetworkTreeView.DataContext = viewModel;
    NetworkTreeView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Protocols;
    _updateDataIsNeeded = true;
}
```

Y mi metodo `Clear`, este es llamado desde la ventana principal junto con otros metodos `Clear` de otros `UserControl`.

```
public void Clear()
{
    lock (SyncRoot)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => viewModel.Protocols.Clear()));
        _lastNodeSelected = null;
    }
}
```

Espero haber explicado mi problema. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Vamos a necesitar mas codigo como por ejemplo el xml completo del TreeView.

Comment: No puedo compartir mi codigo exacto por politicas de la empresa, vere que puedo hacer

Comment: @Tecnologer: De hecho, lo que se pide es un [mcve], no el código exacto.

Comment: Si en eso ando trabajando

Comment: Listo, he añadido mas codigo